# UnicodeDecodeError при использовании Cyrillic в интерфейсе приложения Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

Я пытаюсь использовать кириллицу в интерфейсе, но приложение не запускается. Вот код:

main.py

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import sys

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'other'
        text: 'Другой экран'
        font_size: 50

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: 'other'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
        text: 'back to the home screen'
        font_size: 50
```

Когда я запускаю программу на андроид, получаю:

```
[INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO ] [Python ] v3.6.2 (default, Oct 29 2017, 05:27:57)
[GCC 7.2.0]
[INFO ] [Factory ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO ] [Image ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/TrafficTaxApp/TrafficTaxApp/main.py", line 19, in 
presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/i686-linux-android/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 290, in load_file
data = fd.read()
File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/i686-linux-android/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 186: ordinal not in range(128)
```

На Ubuntu все хорошо, никаких проблем.

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заработало вот так:

main.py

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

# ~presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

with open("presentation.kv", encoding='utf8') as f:
    presentation = Builder.load_string(f.read())


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

MainApp().run()
```

presentation.kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'other'
        text: 'Другой экран'
        font_size: 50

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: 'other'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
        text: 'back to the home screen'
        font_size: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

А макете не нужно указывать кодировку. Кстати, подскажите, как вы установили pygame в PyDroid3?

Ошибка с кодировкой макета часто бывает в Windows. Python 3 в Windows по умолчанию открывает файлы в кодировке win-1251. Чтобы он открывал в utf-8, надо принудительно указывать open(filename, encoding='utf-8') Kivy открывает без указания кодировки, т.е. вам самому надо открывать kv-файл с указанием кодировки, считывать в переменную и передавать её в Builder.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. На этом простом примере получилось. Но на более пока всё равно не получается.
Pygame в PyDroid3 не устанавливал. Запускаю в голом PyDroid3

Comment: в ответах должен быть ответ. Вопросы автору можно в комментариях задать.